# Drag-and-drop Javascript won't work within ajax request on mobile devices

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop, touch

I'm trying to make a feature where users type into a text box which produces suggestions as you type (like Google Instant), then those suggestions can be dragged into boxes on the page. It all worked fine until I discovered touch screen mobile devices don't work with HTML 5 drop and drag. I'm trying to get it work with jquery instead but it's not going smoothly.

The code below displays a draggable image and it works with touch screens and mice.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/head.min.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
<script>
head.js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js','js/ui.js','js/touch.js', function (){
   $('#touchme1').draggable({revert:true});
$('#drop').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
        $(this).css({'border':'#777 dashed 3px','background':'#eee'});
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({'border':'#a33 dashed 3px','background':'#faa'});
    },
    out: function (event, ui){
        $(this).css({'border':'#777 dashed 3px','background':'#eee'});
    }
});
});
</script>
<img src='itemimages/75.jpg' id='touchme1' class='touchBox'>
```

The problem is that when the same code is used within the php file which is called to display search results, the drag and drop doesn't work on mobile devices (but it does on desktops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you may need to attach an event handler to the #touch1 element. The code you posted only looks for #touch1 elements that already exist in the DOM, but as your element is loaded though AJAX, it will not be in the DOM when the page first loads.

You can use `.on()` to attach an event handler to the object.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#touchme1', function(){
    $(this).draggable({revert:true});
});
```

In the above example I am using the `mouseover` event. However you will need to choose an event hander that will work for you with both touch devices and with a mouse.

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/agisom/2/edit

Comment: Thanks very much. That sounds like it would probably fix the problem, unfortunately my lack of javascript skills means I can't work out how to implement it.

Comment: If you add it into the header with your other javascript code it should work. Although like I said, you will need to change the event from mouseover to something that will work on mobile devices, like touch.